# Datetime not getting parsed in CSV in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
import datetime

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['VAR1']).dt.date
```

Pandas is reading the CSV file.

**Below is the error I get. Wondering if anyone knew a fix? Var1 column format is correct. day,month and year.**

> ValueError: time data "13/01/2019 0:00" doesn't match format "%m/%d/%Y
> %H:%M", at position 575. You might want to try: - passing `format` if
> your strings have a consistent format; - passing `format='ISO8601'` if
> your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same
> format; - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred
> for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst`
> alongside this.

[image: Data]

Comment: your datetime format in the screenshot is "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", not "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M". Instead of providing an explicit format, you can set `dayfirst=True` .

Comment: Thank you. This is the easiest method so far.

Comment: Possibility to replace image with text? [Share code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) + easier for [mre].

Answer (score 0):

you could specify format

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['VAR1'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").dt.date
```